# How to enable kernel core dumps on Ubuntu?

Tags: kernel, debugging

Is it possible to get a kernel crash dump on ubuntu? If so, how do I enable it? I have a recurring hang, with systemd sleeping uninterruptably, and I want to figure out what it's doing.

Pointers to TFM gratefully accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind - I just remembered that linux kernels have "crash dumps" not "core dumps" unlike unix kernels, and that gave a more useful response from google.

https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/kernel-crash-dump.html

Comment: It is better to include important parts of the link in the answer itself